# How do you respond using a one-line piece of javascript in a Ruby on Rails controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I haven't been able to find any useful resources online on how to do this. Basically what I'm trying to do is run a simple jQuery `$('#test-div').show();` when my `def show_div` controller action is complete.

I've tried the following and it doesn't work.  It actually renders HTML which is confusing to me. when I explicitly state that the method respond with js.

users_controller.rb

```
  def show_div
    @user = User.first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end

    # also tried
    # render :js => "$('#test-div').show();"
  end
```

show_div.js.erb

```
$('#test-div').show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render :text` should do what you are asking for -- just return raw text (which in your case happens to be JavaScript code) without doing anything to it.